# Error when attempting to upgrade access level of VSTS user

Tags: tfs

I have a team set up in VSTS and I am trying to upgrade certain team members who need access to the test suite functionality.  I have procured several paid enterprise level accounts that show as available.  However, when I attempt to change someone's access level from basic to enterprise I get the following error:
vs1720077: Subscription could not be validated.
I have the top level account so I am not sure why I am not able to upgrade these users.

Comment: Are those Enterprise subscriptions linked to the users' live IDs/Azure AD accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Just as *Daniel* commented, you must link your work ID. For troubleshooting:

> - Make sure in the  https://msdn.microsoft.com portal you have actually    linked your work ID. You still need to explicably do this
>     even if    your MSA and Work ID use the same email address e.g.
>     `user@domain.com`. Using the same email address for both IDs can get
>     confusing, so I would recommend considering you setup your MSA email
>     addresses to not clash with your work ID.
> - When you login to **VSO MAKE SURE YOU USE THE WORK ID LOGIN LINK (LHS    OF DIALOG UNDER VSO LOGO) TO LOGIN WITH A WORK ID AND NOT THE
>     MAIN    LIVEID FIELDS**. I can’t stress this enough, especially if you
>     use the    same email address  for both the MSA and work account
> - If you still get issues with picking up the MSDN subscription
>
>   . In VSO the admin should set the user to be a basic user
>        . In  https://msdn.microsoft.com the user should make sure they did not    make any typo's when linking the work account ID
>
>   . The user should sign out of VSO and back in using their work ID,
>     **MAKE    SURE THEYUSE THE CORRECT WORK ID LOGIN DIALOG**. They should see the    features available to a basic user
>
>   . The VSO admin should change the role assignment in VSO to be MSDN
>     eligible and it should flip over without a problem. There seems to be 
>     no need to logout and back in again.
>
> Source Link: [Why can’t I assign a VSO user as having ‘eligible MSDN’
>   using an AAD work account?](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2015/11/04/Why-cant-I-assign-a-VSO-user-as-having-eligible-MSDN-using-an-AAD-work-account)

Also take a look at this similar issue: [Lost capability when msdn.microsoft.com was forced to my.visualstudio.com link and VSTS Validation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7eaa8964-175f-4365-a50e-6fb959e6169f/lost-capability-when-msdnmicrosoftcom-was-forced-to-myvisualstudiocom-link-and-vsts-validation?forum=TFService)

Comment: nowadays it is https://my.visualstudio.com/subscriptions but other than that, this helped a lot :)